# apache2 mod_rewrite redirect without http body

Tags: mod-rewrite, http, redirect, apache2, 301-redirect

I am currently using Apache mod_rewrite to redirect to HTTPS,
but I would like to remove the body from the response.

How it is currently:

[image: Current response]

Example: How I would like it to be

[image: Desired response]

My redirect configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please add relevant configuration information to the question.

Comment: Is this in .htaccess, or the server config?

Comment: It is in the server config (.conf file)

Comment: When someone asked the same question before, the answer - which I still stand by - was to [not attempt to do it](https://serverfault.com/a/423685/126632).

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Don't make your server lie.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M It's not "lying" - all the real information is contained in the HTTP response _headers_. Sending an empty response body in this instance is simply reducing the size of the response.

Comment: "This question already has an answer here: NGINX 301 and 302..."? No, it's not answered for Apache yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom ErrorDocument for the 301 response, in which you can set an empty response. (Although specifying a custom "error document" for a non-error, ie. for anything other than a 4xx or 5xx status, is not explicitly documented.)

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 301 /errordocs/empty.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Where `/errordocs/empty.html` is literally an empty document.

Alternatively, you can set the `ErrorDocument` to a plain *string*. But you can't set an entirely empty string, as Apache doesn't then see the second argument and aborts with an error: "ErrorDocument takes two arguments".  However, you can reduce this to a single character. For example, to send just a hyphen (`-`) in the response body:

```
ErrorDocument 301 "-"
```

This does, however, set the response body for *all* Apache 301 responses. (However, if this is in the VirtualHost container for port 80 in the server config, then this will be restricted to the HTTP-only redirects anyway.)

Reference: [This answer to a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529566/369434) goes into more detail about [returning an empty response from Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703871/return-empty-response-from-apache).

However, as @MichaelHampton pointed out in comments, whether you should be sending [an empty response body in the case of a redirect](https://serverfault.com/a/423685/49157) is another matter.

> It is in the server config (.conf file)

*Aside:* If this is in the server config, then you should be using a simple mod_alias `Redirect` in the non-HTTPS (port 80) VirtualHost container, instead of mod_rewrite. Using mod_rewrite in this context, to explicitly check the `HTTPS` server variable, is unnecessary. This makes no difference to the error document that is returned.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your great answer. I tried the version with the empty file, sadly without success (I got an additional 500 Internal Server Error), but the single-character version worked. However I am now leaving the body in there since there is no real need to remove it, I just wanted to know if I could remove it. Thank you for all your effort.